# Hibernate: Connecting as SYSDBA to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, hibernate

How to connect to Oracle database as SYSDBA using Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this?

Hibernate is a tool for building database application without engaging with the database in any meaningful way.

SYSDBA is a protocol for connecting to an Oracle database as SYS, the owner of the data dictionary and the most powerful user in the database.  It is an administrative role.  There are very few times when anybody needs to connect as SYS, and the only people who ever need to do so are DBAs.  In my experience DBAs loathe and detest Hibernate applications.

In short, Hibernate provides generic, abstract access to databases whereas SYSDBA demands specific and hands-on access.  Whatever it is you want to achieve there has to be a better way than trying to use SYSDBA through Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The website under development is meant to automate the work of DBAs. So, connecting as sysdba is the basic requirement of the system. Can you suggest other ways to connect as sysdba?

Answer (score 0):

The method that is documented in Oracle's JDBC developer's guide is passing a specific property when getting the connection:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.put("username", "sys");
props.put("password", "some_very_secure_and_secret_password");
props.put("internal_logon", "sysdba");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@....", props);
```

I don't know if Hibernate is flexible enough to customize the way of connecting.

An alternative way is to simply provide `sys as sysdba` as the username (note the spaces!) for the connection. I don't know if this is a supported solution but it seems to work without problems.